# Slim content_for possible refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I have a title renderer in my application.html.slim:

```
title
  - if content_for?(:title)
    = yield(:title)
  - else
    | My another title
```

If there is a content_for :title block, than I yield it. Other way, I render default text 'my another title' in title tag.

All works great, but it seems that code above little dirty. Is there any way to refactor it?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Maybe it's a question better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Did you have any luck with the posted answer?

Comment: No, just line from bottom, but it seems dirty too, because of "My another title" is long string

Comment: I'm confused as to how you'd like to refactor this, then. Can you provide some pseudo-code that might help illustrate? How are you supposed to output `My another title` without actually declaring it somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain whether the following syntax is supported by Slim, but a possible alternative would be a single line ternary output:

```
title = content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : 'My default title'
```

Comment: I asked very stupid question, apologize for requesting your time.

`= if content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : t('labels.site_name')`